# Inequality involving orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vectors

I have to prove the folowing statements are equivalent:

[image]

I have proved:

i) implies ii) because of the Law of cosines.

ii) implies iii) because

$$\left \| x+\lambda y \right \|=\left \| x \right \|^{2}+\left \| \lambda y \right \|^{2} \geq \left \| x \right \|^{2}.$$

iv) implies i) because
$$\left \| x+y \right \|^{2}-\left \| x-y \right \|^{2}=4x \cdot y=0.$$

But I don't know how to prove iii) implies iv). The inequality gives me trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square both sides in (iii). You get a quadratic inequality in $\lambda$ which becomes an equality for $\lambda=0$. That implies that the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial has to be zero. If you write down that condition (which involves $x$ and $y$), you should get (iv).

Comment: How does it become an inequality for $\lambda=0$ and why does that imply that the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial has to be zero?

Comment: @Shambhala If you set $\lambda=0$ both sides are clearly equal. You have a quadratic polynomial $P(\lambda)$ which is always non-negative and is zero at one point, so it has exactly one real root. That happens precisely when the discriminant is zero.